# Upgrade from TYPO3 9 to 10 - Fatal Error in Upgrade Wizard with no extensions enabled

Tags: typo3

I just upgraded my TYPO3 v9 to v10.04.27 and now i get an error in the Upgrade Wizard

(1/1) Error
Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\StringFrontend' not found in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheManager.php line 351

As you can see in the path i also tried already with an older TYPO3 10 Version.

I disabled all extensions before the upgrade. Except the ones that cant be disabled.

So this should be a completely clean TYPO3 10 install (except the Config Files).

I dont know what i can do about this.

Here is the Full Trace:

```
Something went wrong. Please use Check for broken extensions to see if a loaded extension breaks this part of the install tool and unload it.

The box below may additionally reveal further details on what went wrong depending on your debug settings. It may help to temporarily switch to debug mode using Settings > Configuration Presets > Debug settings.

If this error happens at an early state and no full exception back trace is shown, it may also help to manually increase debugging output in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php:['BE']['debug'] => true, ['SYS']['devIPmask'] => '*', ['SYS']['displayErrors'] => 1,['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] => 12290

Ajax error
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) Error
Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\StringFrontend' not found

in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheManager.php line 351
            $backendInstance->initializeObject();
        }

        // New used on purpose, see comment above
        $frontendInstance = new $frontend($identifier, $backendInstance);
        if (!$frontendInstance instanceof FrontendInterface) {
            throw new InvalidCacheException('"' . $frontend . '" is not a valid cache frontend object.', 1464550984);
        }
        if (is_callable([$frontendInstance, 'initializeObject'])) {
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager->createCache()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheManager.php line 157
        if ($this->hasCache($identifier) === false) {
            throw new NoSuchCacheException('A cache with identifier "' . $identifier . '" does not exist.', 1203699034);
        }
        if (!isset($this->caches[$identifier])) {
            $this->createCache($identifier);
        }
        return $this->caches[$identifier];
    }

at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager->getCache()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/DatabaseSchemaService.php line 51
        $cacheManager->setCacheConfigurations($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']);

        $tableDefinitions = '';
        foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'] as $cacheName => $_) {
            $backend = $cacheManager->getCache($cacheName)->getBackend();
            if (method_exists($backend, 'getTableDefinitions')) {
                $tableDefinitions .= LF . $backend->getTableDefinitions();
            }
        }
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\DatabaseSchemaService->getCachingFrameworkRequiredDatabaseSchema()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/DatabaseSchemaService.php line 33
     * @param AlterTableDefinitionStatementsEvent $event
     */
    public function addCachingFrameworkDatabaseSchema(AlterTableDefinitionStatementsEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->addSqlData($this->getCachingFrameworkRequiredDatabaseSchema());
    }

    /**
     * Get schema SQL of required cache framework tables.
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\DatabaseSchemaService->addCachingFrameworkDatabaseSchema()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 51
        if ($event instanceof StoppableEventInterface && $event->isPropagationStopped()) {
            return $event;
        }
        foreach ($this->listenerProvider->getListenersForEvent($event) as $listener) {
            $listener($event);
            if ($event instanceof StoppableEventInterface && $event->isPropagationStopped()) {
                break;
            }
        }
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Schema/SqlReader.php line 75
            }
        }

        /** @var AlterTableDefinitionStatementsEvent $event */
        $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new AlterTableDefinitionStatementsEvent($sqlString));
        $sqlString = $event->getSqlData();

        return implode(LF . LF, $sqlString);
    }
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\SqlReader->getTablesDefinitionString()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service/UpgradeWizardsService.php line 156
     */
    public function getBlockingDatabaseAdds(): array
    {
        $sqlReader = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SqlReader::class);
        $databaseDefinitions = $sqlReader->getCreateTableStatementArray($sqlReader->getTablesDefinitionString());

        $schemaMigrator = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SchemaMigrator::class);
        $databaseDifferences = $schemaMigrator->getSchemaDiffs($databaseDefinitions);

at TYPO3\CMS\Install\Service\UpgradeWizardsService->getBlockingDatabaseAdds()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Controller/UpgradeController.php line 1042
        $this->lateBootService->loadExtLocalconfDatabaseAndExtTables(false);
        $adds = [];
        $needsUpdate = false;
        try {
            $adds = $this->upgradeWizardsService->getBlockingDatabaseAdds();
            $this->lateBootService->resetGlobalContainer();
            if (!empty($adds)) {
                $needsUpdate = true;
            }
at TYPO3\CMS\Install\Controller\UpgradeController->upgradeWizardsBlockingDatabaseAddsAction()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Middleware/Maintenance.php line 246
                    'Unknown action method ' . $action . ' in controller ' . $controllerName,
                    1505216027
                );
            }
            $response = $controller->$action($request);
        }

        return $response;
    }
at TYPO3\CMS\Install\Middleware\Maintenance->process()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php line 121
            }

            public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
            {
                return $this->middleware->process($request, $this->next);
            }
        };
    }

at class@anonymous/srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php:103$bc->handle()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Middleware/NormalizedParamsAttribute.php line 45
     */
    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $request = $request->withAttribute('normalizedParams', NormalizedParams::createFromRequest($request));
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Middleware\NormalizedParamsAttribute->process()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php line 172

                if (!$middleware instanceof MiddlewareInterface) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(get_class($middleware) . ' does not implement ' . MiddlewareInterface::class, 1516821342);
                }
                return $middleware->process($request, $this->next);
            }
        };
    }
}
at class@anonymous/srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php:138$bd->handle()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php line 78
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->tip->handle($request);
    }

    /**
     * Seed the middleware stack with the inner request handler
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php line 85
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    protected function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->requestHandler->handle($request);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the application and shut it down afterwards
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AbstractApplication->handle()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Http/Application.php line 52
    protected function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        $this->initializeContext();
        $request = $request->withAttribute('applicationType', SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_INSTALL);
        return parent::handle($request)
            ->withHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
    }

    /**
at TYPO3\CMS\Install\Http\Application->handle()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php line 97
    final public function run(callable $execute = null)
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->handle(
                ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals()
            );
            if ($execute !== null) {
                call_user_func($execute);
            }
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AbstractApplication->run()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/install.php line 105

call_user_func(function () {
    $classLoader = require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::run(1, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_INSTALL);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::init($classLoader, true)->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Install\Http\Application::class)->run();
});
at {closure}()
in /srv/typo3_src-10.4.20/typo3/install.php line 106
call_user_func(function () {
    $classLoader = require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::run(1, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_INSTALL);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::init($classLoader, true)->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Install\Http\Application::class)->run();
});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have to tried to delete all extensions except the ones from TYPO3 core? I had some errors in my installations if extension are deactivated but not deleted. Git it a try.

Comment: Hello Heinz. Thank you. Thats it. I just deleted all the extensions folders and its working.

Comment: Nice. I wrote an answer. Please accept it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all extensions except the ones from TYPO3 core. Then cache will be rebuild without not needed classes.

I had some errors in my installations if extension are only deactivated but not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using the StringFrontend somewhere, which was deprecated [in TYPO3 9.2](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Deprecation-81434-StringCacheFrontendDeprecated.html).

Can you check your `LocalConfiguration.php` and `AdditionalConfiguration.php` if you find "StringFrontend" anywhere and replace it with `VariableFrontend` or remove it completely? (as suggested in the migration path)

Comment: Hello CDRO. Unfortunately there is already VariableFrontend set. 
'frontend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\VariableFrontend', for extbase_object

There is a PhpFrontend present for autoloader